# How can I get Haskell readline installing under Cygwin?

Tags: haskell, cygwin, readline

Here's the message I get when trying to install in via cabal-install:

```
$ cabal install --extra-include-dirs="C:\no_spaces\cygwin\usr\include" --extra-lib-dirs="C:\no_spaces\cygwin\lib" readline
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring readline-1.0.1.0...
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for GNUreadline.framework... checking for readline... no
checking for tputs in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline in -lreadline... yes
checking for rl_readline_version... yes
checking for rl_begin_undo_group... yes
checking for rl_erase_empty_line... yes
checking for rl_free_undo_list... yes
checking for rl_completion_word_break_hook in -lreadline... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.mk
config.status: creating readline.buildinfo
config.status: creating include/HsReadlineConfig.h
config.status: include/HsReadlineConfig.h is unchanged
cabal.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:
* Missing header file: HsReadline.h
* Missing C libraries: readline, ncurses
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
readline-1.0.1.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I have readline.h and whatnot, and clearly it seems to find them. The lack of HsReadline.h being an issue seems strange: isn't that part of the package I'm trying to *install?*

Any advice on how to get this working would be appreciated. I've spent days mucking around trying to get this to work, whether under gnuWin32 readline, MinGW, or cygwin.

Comment: Have you tried using the
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= flags to point to the folders where your libraries are located?

Have you installed readline-dev and ncurses-dev?

Tell us what exactly you've tried before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to venture a guess that what's throwing Cygwin off is the DOS/Windows-style path: "C:\no_spaces\cygwin\usr\include"

Try navigating to these files in the Cygwin shell. It'll probably look something like "/cygdrive/c/no_spaces/cygwin/usr/include"

The message about HsReadline.h is probably a red herring. The real issue is that Cabal can't find the underlying dev library to compile against.